# Dockers not reachable after upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04.1

Tags: server, 22.04, docker

I just upgraded from 20.04.4 to 22.04.1. Everything seemed to be ok during the process, I have also update the third part source list to jammy (including docker) and used apt upgrade to bring it to the right version.

After all of it, all dockers in bridge mode are not reachable. I can see that all interfaces/networks are up and running. I tried to use update-alternatives --config iptables but it didn't resolve the issue. I stopped the UFW to make sure it was not causing the issue.

The problem still happens. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you include the output of `docker ps`, as well as other commands that might help (like `ifconfig`).